# Try to read a file into byte[], but eventually get a null length array

Tags: java, android, arrays, uri, inputstream

I am new to Android and also this is my first time ask question at StackOverflow. And please forgive my poor English if I didn't say everything clearly.

I am trying to turn a file into byte[] so that I can upload that file to a server later. Here is my code.

```
        InputStream io = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
        byte[] buff = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
            File file = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
            int size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            io = conn.getInputStream();
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int byteWritten = 0;
            int byteCount = 0;
            buff = new byte[size];
            out.write(buff, byteWritten, byteCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
*        multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", "Android_Flask_" + ".mp4", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*mp4"), buff));
        RequestBody postBodyfile = multipartBodyBuilder.build();
        postRequest(postUrl, postBodyfile);
```

and here is error I got

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.contata.FlaskClient.Uploader, PID: 24319
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7137)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27418)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7540)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7137) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27418) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7540) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at okhttp3.RequestBody.create(RequestBody.java:78)
*        at com.contata.FlaskClient.Uploader.MainActivity.connectServer(MainActivity.java:171)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7160) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7137) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27418) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7540) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

the line 171 is
        `multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", "Android_Flask_" + ".mp4", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*mp4"), buff));`

`selectedfilesPaths` contain the Uri of file.
Seem like the `buff[]` didn't get any thing from `InputStream`

I tried different ways of turn file into byte[] and still cant deal with it. Always get same error at same place.
Maybe something else lead to this problem?
Thanks alot.

==================EDITED================

I change the sequence of some lines so that I dont have to initial the buff[] to null. Now the app will not crash. But my server only receive a 0kb empty file. What else can I have a try？

```
        InputStream io = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
        int size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            io = conn.getInputStream();
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int byteWritten = 0;
            int byteCount = 0;
            out.write(buff, byteWritten, byteCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", "Android_Flask_" + ".mp4", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*mp4"), buff));
        RequestBody postBodyfile = multipartBodyBuilder.build();
        postRequest(postUrl, postBodyfile);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `buff` is correctly initialized and your `try` statement doesn't catch any exception?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.. You just need to store the file data into buff.

```
InputStream io = null;
//ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
int size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
byte[] buff = new byte[size];
try {
    URL url = new URL(String.valueOf(selectedfilesPaths));
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    io = new FileInputStream(file); // added
    //io = conn.getInputStream();
    //out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //int byteWritten = 0;
    //int byteCount = 0;
    //out.write(buff, byteWritten, byteCount);
    io.read(buff, 0, size);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
multipartBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", "Android_Flask_" + ".mp4", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*mp4"), buff));
RequestBody postBodyfile = multipartBodyBuilder.build();
postRequest(postUrl, postBodyfile);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your works really help me alot, now the app won't crash up. But a new exception coming up, The IDE says "java.nio.file.nosuchfileexception,no suchh file or dir", seem that it cant read out the file (Im sure the uri is correct and I already give app permission to file system).

Comment: Well, nobody knows for sure why because you didn't mention the variable `selectedfilesPaths`.  If it's a URI, better use `Uri#parse(selectedfilesPaths)`. Try placing your files in `/sdcard/Download` folder too.